# Proving a particular cosine rule

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

If I have the constraint

$$k\cos(x) = -\cos(y)$$
where $k, x, y$ are all positive real values, is there a way to prove that $x = y = \pi/2$ so both sides go to $0$?

It's the only "obvious" solution I see but I don't know how to prove there isn't some other sneaky solution somewhere.

Comment: No... there is no way.  That is because you give a value of $k$ and $x$ such that $k \cos x \leq 1$ and you can always find a $y$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: **Hint**: what do we know about the parity of the $cos$ function?


Are you therefore sure that there are no other solutions?

Comment: Counterexample: $k = 1$, $y = \pi -x $ works for $x\neq y \neq \frac\pi2$